# How to apply the multiple data filters to DataView WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 6 data filters in my page including two date filters. Filtering is working fine, if I select it one by one. How can I do the filtering by all the currently selected filters at once ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need compound filter for this, check this for more information:
http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/15/compound-filtering-in-data-view-web-parts-dvwps-with-sharepoint-designer/

check this post 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/31247304-1352-4aed-82b6-6fa9ce5e83b2/multiple-filters-in-data-form-web-partdata-view-web-part?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Please do not only provide links as answers. If the link breaks the answer will be of very little help, it is better to add the important steps from your links to the post :)

Comment: sure, i will. i am new on this forum so i think take time to learn new things.

Comment: No problem, it is nice to have you here! :)